# Is time.sleep(n) a good way to wait in a python script or should I use an external module?

Tags: python-3.x

Just wondering if I should use that, or an external script like TwistedSheduler for "suspending"

thanks

Comment: what do you mean with `"suspending"`? also will be a very personal/opinion based answer.....

Comment: I mean, in js, there is recomended to use setinterval instead of sleep. (due performance) and my question is if thats the case even for python.

Comment: import sched and import threading.Timer are your friends depending how you want to have that impelemented.